# Don't show web push notification when app is opened

Tags: angular, apple-push-notifications, web-push

I've implemented web push notifications on our PWA and got everything working, however the notifications also show up when the PWA app is opened, which makes them less useful.

payload from server is:

```
    {
  "notification": {
    "title": "Dylan",
    "body": "test message",
    "icon": null,
    "badge": null,
    "requireInteraction": true,
    "action_url": null,
    "vibrate": [
      100,
      50,
      100
    ],
    "data": {
      "convId": 7343039,
      "badge": 1,
      "messageType": 1,
      "message": "test message",
      "fromUserId": 1256086,
      "pushNotificationType": 1,
      "badgeCount": 4
    },
    "actions": []
  }
}
```

Using `Angular SwPush` on the client to create a subscription.

My desktop chrome browser as well as IOS pwa app both have the same problem: notifications appear even when the app is in foreground.
Is it even possible to only have them show up when the app is in the background/closed?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a service which will check for inactivity or away from screen
I have implemented similar kind of thing.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from './event.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InactivityService {

  private _isScreenActive: boolean;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }

  public set isScreenActive(isActive: boolean) {
    this._isScreenActive = isActive;
  }

  public get isScreenActive() {
    return this._isScreenActive;
  }

  /**
  * @description register visibility change event to dom.
  * @isScreenActive false when user is away from tab, true when back on tab.
  */
  applyEvent() {
    let visibilityHidden, visibilityChange;
    // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
    if (typeof document.hidden !== 'undefined') {
      visibilityHidden = 'hidden';
      visibilityChange = 'visibilitychange';
    } else if (typeof (document as any).mozHidden !== 'undefined') {
      visibilityHidden = 'mozHidden';
      visibilityChange = 'mozvisibilitychange';
    } else if (typeof (document as any).msHidden !== 'undefined') {
      visibilityHidden = 'msHidden';
      visibilityChange = 'msvisibilitychange';
    } else if (typeof (document as any).webkitHidden !== 'undefined') {
      visibilityHidden = 'webkitHidden';
      visibilityChange = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
    }

    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, () => {
      if (document[visibilityHidden]) {
        this.isScreenActive = false;
      } else {
        this.isScreenActive = true;
        this.eventService.broadcast(this.eventService.eventNames.SCREENACTIVEAGAIN, {});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how would this prevent swPush from broadcasting the notification? Roll your own service worker?

Comment: you might be subscribing it in your app, manage the subscription accordingly.